# Apache Storm aggregation rules for missing expected events in rolling time-period

Tags: real-time, distributed-computing, complex-event-processing, apache-storm, apache-samza

My use-case is to identify entities from which expected events have not been received after X amount of time in real-time rather than using batch jobs. For Example:

If we have received PaymentInitiated event at time T but didn't receive either of PaymentFailed / PaymentAborted / PaymentSucedded by T+X, then raise a trigger saying PaymentStuck along with details of PaymentIntitiated event.

How can I model such use-cases in Apache Storm as it is rolling time period X on each event, rather than fixed time interval.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 1):

For Storm, would need to put all your logic into your UDF code using low level Java API (I doubt that Trindent is helpful). I never worked with Samza and cannot provide any help for it (or judge which system would be the better fit for your problem).

In Storm for example, you could assign a timestamp to each tuple in `Spout.nextTuple()`, and buffer all tuples of an incomplete payment within a Bolt in descending order of the timestamp. Each time `Bolt.execute()` is called, you can compare the timestamp of the new tuple with the head (ie, oldest tuple) of your queue. If the input tuple has a larger timestamep than head-T plus X, you know that your head tuple times out and you can raise your trigger for it.

Of course, you need to do `fieldsGrouping()` to ensure that all tuples belonging to the same payment are processed by the same Bolt instance. You might also need to somewhat order the incoming bolt tuples by timestamp or use more advance time-out logic to deal with out-of-order tuples (with regard to increasing timestamps).

Depending on you latency requirement and input stream rate you might also use "tick tuples" to trigger the comparison of the head tuple with this dummy tick tuple. Or as an ever stricter implementation, do all this logic directly in `Spout.next()` (if you know that all tuples of a payment go through the same Spout instance).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. In the above approach, the check for timestamp is done only when Bolt.execute() is invoked which will be done only on an event. But my requirement is to raise the trigger even when the desired event is missing... How do handle such scenario? Did i mis-understood anything?

Comment: You got it. The idea is to raise the trigger when another event that is younger (ie, comes after the potential last event of a payment) comes in. If you have tuples ordered by timestamp, you know that the last event is really missing (ie, you react indirectly). You will never be able to react on a missing event directly because there is nothing to react on whatsoever.